# Lost phone contacts after deleting Gmail acount

Tags: google-account, google-contacts, account-recovery

How can I restore my Gmail account once I've deleted it and it's been almost a month since I deleted from my iPhone 10? I have lost most of my important contacts and no other way to recover

Answer (score 1):

> ### **Recover a recently deleted Google Account**
>
> If you deleted your Google Account, you may be able to get it back. If it’s been a while since you deleted your account, you may not be able to recover the data in your account. If you recover your account, you'll be able to sign in as usual to Gmail, Google Play, and other Google services.
>
> 1. **[Follow the steps to recover your account](https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery)**.
>
>    - You'll be asked some questions to confirm it's your account. Answer as best you can.
>    - If you're having trouble, try the tips to complete account recovery steps.
> 2. If your account is recovered, create a password that you haven't already used with this account. Learn how to create a strong password.
>
> ---
>
> **https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6236295?hl=en**